# Multithreading & Entity Framework

Tags: multithreading, entity-framework, c#-5.0

I have a pool of the threads and they do the bunch of the operations with the database. However the amount of the threads is huge so it's very possible that 2 threads would like to use the same record from the database at the same time.
In ado.net I'd use transactions to handle this situation.
What should I use in entity framework to avoid mentioned problem?

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is - is it one of concurrency?  Or is it one of 'caching' (to use the term loosely) in that you want to have a common 'cache' that teach thread can pull data from if it has already been requested by a different thread?

Comment: I guess the major issue here is the concurrency: 2 threads can try to update the data  in the database at the same time.

Comment: I believe you can also use transaction in EF (transaction scope), see this https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738523(v=vs.100).aspx